linked in fetch posts 2024 failing with 404
All the info to fetch posts on linkedin seems deprecated
I have added all the scopes to my auth, and even tried linked in premium...
also found that  I cannot have social feeds?
All scope permissions I see are w_ (write)
Like
"w_member_social",
So is it possible to fetch posts? for a user? me? or a company?
